# How correct install Admin template Gentelella on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, yarnpkg, ruby-on-rails-6

I want to connect the gentelella template to my rails 6 project.
The project is completely empty.
Installed via yarn add gentelella.
Further in the file app /javascript/packs/application.js added

```
require ("gentelella")
```

But when you open any page, it gives an error that Jquery is not connected. If I understand correctly all the dependencies should have been connected from the vendors folder but this did not happen, at least for rails 6 it works for a friend.
Tell me how to properly connect all the dependencies so as not to install them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [gentelella-rails](https://github.com/mwlang/gentelella-rails) gem which is made for Rails 5 and greater.

There are [some installation instructions to follow from the README.md file](https://github.com/mwlang/gentelella-rails#installation) that should help you getting it working.

While this gem should ease the installation, it uses the Rails Assets Pipeline (aka Sprockets), while in Rails 6 webpacker is now the default so you would have to bring back the sprockets gem.

Otherwise if you'd like to go the "hard" way, you have to require all the dependencies as it is [described in their documentation](https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/gentelella/blob/master/vendors/jquery/README.md).

### Update

Regarding jQuery particularly, you would have to add it to webpack like so:

```js
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
})
```